# How global scope works in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

```
 var a = 10
 function fun(){
     var b = 20
 }
fun()
```

In this code var a has global scope but var b dont have global scope but functional scope. But as fun() itself is global function which will be global to everywhere why var b is not global

Comment: `functional scope` mean `b` is only visible inside the function. It doesn't matter what the scope of the name `fun` is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: `var b` exists only when you **call** the `function fun`, not at any time.

Answer (score 1):

A variable declared outside a function becomes GLOBAL.
Variables inside the Global scope can be accessed and altered in any other scope.

**Global Scope:**

```
// global scope
var a = 1;

function one() {
  alert(a); // alerts '1'
}
```

**Local scope:**

```
// global scope
var a = 1;

function two(a) { // passing (a) makes it local scope
  alert(a); // alerts the given argument, not the global value of '1'
}

// local scope again
function three() {
  var a = 3;
  alert(a); // alerts '3'
}
```

Global scope lives as long as your application lives. Local Scope lives as long as your functions are called and executed.

Here, b is inside a function so b is a local variable and it has a local scope, and a is a global variable and it lives when the application lives, and b lives when fun() lives.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the `b` variable inside `fun()` so that varaiable is global only inside that function, If you need to make the variable global which all the methods can us, You have to declare as global

```
var a = 10
var b = 0;
 function fun(){
     this.b = 20
 }
fun()
```